# Understanding stage 2 of the PYIN algorithm

Tags: python, hidden-markov-model

I am reading the PYIN[1] research paper, and I am having difficulty understanding stage 2. I have looked at the Librosa[2] implementation, however, I would like to clarify my understanding.
From Equation 6 in the PYIN[1] paper, it appears that $(1-\sum_k P^*_k)$ is the difference between unity and the sum of the voiced probabilities assigned to discrete frequency bins within a frame.

Any help would really be appreciated as I am new to Hidden Markov Models.

Thank you.

[1] Mauch, M. and Dixon, S., 2014, May. pYIN: A fundamental frequency estimator using probabilistic threshold distributions. In 2014 ieee international conference on acoustics, speech and signal processing (icassp) (pp. 659-663). IEEE.

[2] Librosa.org. (2014). librosa.core.pitch — librosa 0.10.1dev documentation. [online] Available at: https://librosa.org/doc/main/_modules/librosa/core/pitch.html#pyin [Accessed 15 Apr. 2023].